# How to store multiple elements in a list

Tags: c#, playwright

Using Playwright and C#, I'm trying to perform user actions and verifications on a series of three radio buttons in my test app by locating them and storing them in a list which I can iterate over/perform different actions on.
The following code locates the three elements in the page

```
Page.Locator ("div[id='basic'] ph-radio-button");
```

If I try to put the element into a list and click on one of them like so:

```
list<ILocator> buttons;
buttons = (List<ILocator>)Page.Locator("div[id='basic'] ph-radio-button");

await buttons[0].ClickAsync();
```

The test fails with an error:

> strict mode violation: "div[id='basic'] ph-radio-button" resolved to 3 elements: message

According to the Playwright documentation I should be able to use the 'Nth' matching element so I tried the following to add each item to my list:

```
List<ILocator> buttons = new List<ILocator>();  
buttons.Add(Page.Locator("div[id='basic'] ph-radio-button").Nth(0));
```

But this results in the same error.

Is there a way that I can find the elements and store them in a list similar to how you can achieve this in Selenium using `findElements` method which would look something like this:

```
List<WebElement> buttons;
buttons = (driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("div[id='basic'] ph-radio-button")));
```

Comment: From there Release Notes "Selector ambiguity is a common problem in automation testing. strict mode ensures that your selector points to a single element and throws otherwise." and "Also, locators are "strict" by default!". See https://playwright.dev/docs/release-notes#%EF%B8%8F-new-strict-mode

Comment: Can you share the piece of html where those radios are? Maybe I can prepare a xpath selector to get each of them

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work in the end:

```
var list = Page.Locator("div[id='basic'] ph-radio- 
button").ElementHandleAsync();
```

stores each element in a read only list